# kernel exported symbols vs global symbols vs static global?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am little bit stack with kernel symbols type meaning.
Simple static symbols have the same meaning like C static. So local static variable have local scope and static allocation. Static functions scope is a file. But what about static exported symbols? How to deal with `EXPORT_SYMBOL()`, `EXPORT_PER_CPU_SYMBOL()`, `EXPORT_UNUSED_SYMBOL()` if macro export static symbol? What is the difference between global and exported symbols? Is it linker responsibility to add additional info for exported symbols? Is global static variable built-in kernel visible in all the kernel and loadable module?

Kernel exported symbols can be accessed from loadable module. Is it good style touch such symbols inside kernel.
When kernel resolve symbols is it lookup thru kernel symbols table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Conceptually**, using `static` keyword with function declaration means *internal linkage* -- so such function is only visible within single translation unit (*.o file). This may involve inlining of that function (in which case it will be unusable further), but since `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` takes address of static function, compiler should disable inlining optimization.

**Implementation** is a bit more complicated. This *internal* and *external linkage* rules are only apply to static `ld` linker which works when `vmlinux` or kernel module is built. Normally symbol with *external linkage* is added to `symtab` ELF section and when dynamic linker `ld.so` loads *shared object* it reads that section.

But when module is loaded Linux Kernel uses separate symbol table `ksymtab`. `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` adds symbol to that table, but this process is completely transparent to compiler-linker toolchain thus it is not related with *internal* and *external linkage* at all.